# How to make a specific fragment of an NSAttributedString a specific color in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with an `NSAttributedString` with the following code:

```
// just creating from a notification.mainCopy!
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString();
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: notification.mainCopy!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)!])

// a notification will have a blueMainCopy1 - just a test so no this could be done better
// How to make the blueMainCopy1 blue?
var myItalicizedRangeBlue = (notification.mainCopy! as NSString).rangeOfString(notification.blueMainCopy1!)
let blueFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic", size:14.0) // how to make blue
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: blueFont!, range: myItalicizedRangeBlue)
```

How would I add information to blueFont to make it blue in this case?

Is there some way to add:

```
  let blueAttrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()]
```

or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have this:

```
let blueFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic", size:14.0)
myMutableString.addAttribute(
    NSFontAttributeName, value: blueFont!, 
    range: myItalicizedRangeBlue)
```

And this:

```
let blueAttrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()]
```

So now just add another attribute:

```
myMutableString.addAttributes(
    blueAttrs, range: myItalicizedRangeBlue) // or any desired range
```

Or, combine the attributes first and add them together, if they have the same range:

```
let blueFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic", size:14.0)
let blueAttrs = [
    NSFontAttributeName : blueFont!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()
]
myMutableString.addAttributes(
    blueAttrs, range: myItalicizedRangeBlue)
```

Comment: ahh - just needing to fix something on a project. Maybe I need to read more Programming iOS8